# Do we need a technology tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

There have been a few questions related to electronic dictionaries or other electronic resources for studying Korean

[Why do some words show XX-X다 (들어-오다) form in a dictionary?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1850/why-do-some-words-show-xx-x%EB%8B%A4-form-in-a-dictionary)

[What is a good digital Korean-English dictionary?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/what-is-a-good-digital-korean-english-dictionary)

[Websites and internet resources for learning Korean](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/537/websites-and-internet-resources-for-learning-korean?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Are there any online tools available for entering Korean text?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/171/are-there-any-online-tools-available-for-entering-korean-text)

Would it be necessary to have a [technology](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) tag for such questions? Or may be some other tag to specify that it's about electronic resources regarding Korean?

Comment: I think "resources" would be better than "technology".

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so - We already have 'resources' and 'tools', one of which would probably be relevant to most 'electronic' questions (if we had that tag).

*If* we wanted to be more specific (e.g. if we get lots and lots of such questions), I wonder if 'electronic' would actually help anyone; Might specific tags like 'android-app' or 'website' be more helpful? But sub-dividing things too much has its own problems.

Comment: I think we want to keep these questions to a single, limited category. I don't mean we should limit our scopes, but these questions aren't exactly many in number, so creating many tags would produce many tiny "fragmented" tags that nobody even knows exist (hence wouldn't be helpful in categorizing questions or improving seachability.).

Comment: @busukxuan Do you think that 'resources' and 'tools' are usefully distinct, though? I think I do...

Comment: I don't know, in a sense tools are also resources, though not exactly. We should probably consider how many different questions the tools tag can contain.

Comment: Now you are a moderator, please consider this yardstick or standard, if you will. How many Korean learners will this resource-request question help? I think it is the worst question that can be asked on any language site. Your opinion might differ, but let's not waste so much time on this type of general reference question. If we have one canonical post like English, Japanese and other language sites, we don't have to discuss this issue further.

Comment: @Rathony I personally agree it's better to have consolidated resources posts rather than lots of posts - which was the reasoning behind [this meta post](http://meta.korean.stackexchange.com/questions/53/questions-that-are-lists-of-resources) which was upvoted, but not yet replied to. I'm not quite sure what that says about what the community thinks, so while I converted my 'songs' question to wiki, I'm hesitant to do anything about others.

Answer (score 1):

No. 1 question out of the four you listed has nothing to do with any dictionary or resources. I think it is more related with how a compound word works in Korean and how Korean dictionary separates a compound word for a pause in pronunciation.

I don't think the remaining 3 questions need to be kept separated as they are basically asking for the same thing. Please consider merging the 3 questions. We can have one canonical post that has a list of resources for learning Korean.

If there is another question requesting for resources in the future, we can close it as duplicate asking the OP to visit the linked question. I think [resources](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) would be fine for those questions.

English Language and Usage: [What good reference works on English are available?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available)

Japanese Language: [Resources for learning Japanese](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese)

Both sites migrate a resource-request question on the main board to Meta and close it as duplicate of the canonical post. The reason is very obvious. A request for resources is a general reference question and we can have just one canonical post which can help current and future users. Also, if we have just one post, it is easier to keep editing it when we find new helpful resources to add to the list.

**I don't think we necessarily need to migrate the resource-request questions to Meta as Meta is to discuss Korean SE's workings and policies.**

Comment: Let me post an answer to your Meta question when I have time. Moderators can read the comments even if they are deleted. That's why I delete my obsolete comments whenever I find them. I don't like the idea of moving the comments to the chat which will not be visited by so many in the future. I have saved an image of the comments which will be summarized and posted as an answer to your question.

Comment: True, mods are blessed with the 'timeline' view!

Comment: Is it really blessing? I doubt it. I posted an answer to your question. http://meta.korean.stackexchange.com/questions/53/questions-that-are-lists-of-resources/114#114

Comment: @topomorto Did you delete my comment on http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1866/what-are-the-differences-in-usage-and-meaning-between-%EC%95%84%EB%A6%84%EB%8B%B5%EB%8B%A4-%EC%98%88%EC%81%98%EB%8B%A4-%EC%9D%B4%EC%81%98%EB%8B%A4-and-%EA%B3%B1%EB%8B%A4